# How to Append the data to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function where on button click I add columns, now what I want is on button click the column I am adding, I want that to append to another div in my case both button and appended data both are added in same div for now

Here is the code I am working on

```
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {             
    $("button[id='columnadd']").click(function () {
       // create the element
       var domElement = $('<div id="shoppingCart' + i++ + '" class="shoppingCart"><h2 class="ui-widget-header">Add Menu Items Here</h2><aside class="ui-widget-content" id="droppable"><ol><li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li></ol></aside></div>');

       $(this).after(domElement);
       // at this point you have domElement in your page
       //.appendTo("#columnhoder")
       // make it droppable
       domElement.find("ol").droppable({
           accept: '.small_box li',
           greedy: true,
           drop: function (event, ui) {
               alert(1);
               makeItDroppableToo(event, ui, this);
               //$(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
               //$("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);                         
           }
       });
});
```

i want this

```
var domElement = $('<div id="shoppingCart' + i++ + '" class="shoppingCart"><h2 class="ui-widget-header">Add Menu Items Here</h2><aside class="ui-widget-content" id="droppable"><ol><li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li></ol></aside></div>');
```

to append to this div

```
<div id="columnholder">div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use appendTo:

```
domElement.appendTo('#columnholder');
```

Comment: Well, you should check your spelling: 'columnhoder'. Letter 'l' is missung. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ud2Rc/8/

Comment: The jsfiddle also needs closure for `(document).ready(function() {` and to select the jQuery framework; fixing that it works.

Comment: @Simon: sorry, I haven't seen that.
He gave the right answer before me ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$("#columnholder").append(domElement)` should work

[jQuery Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: no use the colunms are not added now...button click is not working

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery this is quite easy. You just have to select your container and then use the append method on it. e.g.:

```
$('#columnholder').append('your html code or something like that');
```

Take a look at: http://api.jquery.com/append/